# Gradient and Hessian of vector multiplication

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, vector-analysis, hessian-matrix

I was asked to find gradient ($\nabla f(x)$) and Hessian ($H(f(x))$) of $f(x)=(a^T x)\cdot (b^T x)$, where $x$, $a$, and $b$ are n-dimensional column vectors.

I was not taught how to find them with respect to vectors of general form.

Here is what I've done so far using intuition from calculus and linear algebra, but I think there are some issues.

$f(x)=(a^T\cdot x)\cdot (b^T\cdot x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} x_{i}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i} x_{i}$.

$\nabla f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i} x_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} x_{i}$, using the product rule.

$H=\frac{\mathrm{d \nabla f(x)}}{\mathrm{d} x} = 2\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i{}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i{}$.

Could you say if I'm wrong and give some intuition how to convert these into short vector form again. Any book or reference link with examples like this are appreciated.

Comment: The gradient should be vector-valued, not scalar-valued. It seems as if you're trying to differentiate with respect to all $x_i$'s at once when that should be done separately.

Comment: @Thorgott But there are n of $x_{i}$!

Comment: Yes, and the gradient is the vector containing the $n$ partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to these $n$ $x_i$'s. Review your definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a colon as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A$$
and define the matrix
$$M=ab^T$$
Write the function in terms of this matrix. Then calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 f
 &= {\rm Tr}(a^Tx\;x^Tb) \\
 &= {\rm Tr}(ba^Txx^T) \\
 &= M:xx^T \\
df
 &= M:(dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T) \\
 &= (M+M^T):dx\,x^T \\
 &= (M+M^T)\,x:dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= (M+M^T)\,x
 \;=\; g \qquad\big({\rm gradient\,vector}\big) \\
}$$
Now calculate the gradient of the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= (M+M^T)\,dx \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
 &= (M+M^T) \;=\; H\qquad\big({\rm Hessian\,matrix}\big) \\
}$$